# Why can't I get my date input on my Form to send via HTTP?

Tags: html, http

First issue:
The form I'm creating is to post information to a CRM called Granot. For some reason the date input and the drop down options won't post.

I took out the type="date" and the post went through, but I would like my users to have a calendar to use.

Second issue:
After submitting the form I would like the user to be redirected to a thank you page and not to the post gateway URL.

Here is the Developer's guide I found on the granot website. Is there anyone on here who would be more familiar with this document? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VMpPFi4c4EhQUg9qab4tPkypgnUQF4U7L8Y-HU8I-R0/preview

I saw on the table in the document a redirurl name to add. I wouldn't know how to use it though.

EDIT: After submitting the form it takes me to actions page and says:
 "0,16, Move date has to be greater than today,0,0"

```
<form name="basicform" id="get_quote_from_test" method="POST" action="https://lead.hellomoving.com/LEADSGWHTTP.lidgw?&API_ID=E432CD67C51E">
      <div id="form_cotent">
        <div class="regForm">

          <div id="step_1">
            <div align="center" class="tab">

              <h3 align="center">Compare Rates and Save Money!</h3>
              <h2 align="center">About Your Move</h2>

              <input placeholder="From Zipcode" oninput="this.className = ''" name="ozip">

              <input placeholder="To Zipcode" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dzip">

              <input type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="movedte">

              <select name="movesize">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Size of your Move</option>
                <option value="Partial Home" name="movesize">Partial Home</option>
                <option value="Studio" name="movesize">Studio</option>
                <option value="1 Bedroom" name="movesize">1 Bedroom</option>
                <option value="2 bedrooms" name="movesize">2 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="3 bedrooms" name="movesize">3 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="4 bedrooms" name="movesize">4 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="More than 4 bedrooms" name="movesize">More than 4 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="Office" name="movesize">Office</option>
              </select><br>


            </div>

            <div align="center" class="">
              <button id="step1_fwd" class="btn bttn1" type="button">
                <span class="text">Start Your Quote</span>


              </button>
              <!--<button id="step1_fwd" class="btn btn-primary bttn1" type="button">Start Your Quote</button>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---- Step 2 --->
          <div id="step_2" class="step_2" style="display: none;">
            <div align="center" class="tab">
              <h2>Step 2</h2>
              <h3>Contact Info</h3>

              <input placeholder="First name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="firstname">

              <input placeholder="Last Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="lastname">

              <input placeholder="E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email">

              <input placeholder="Phone" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone1">
            </div>

            <div align="center">

              <button type="button" class="prevBtn" id="step2-bck">
                <span class="txt">Back</span>
              </button>

              <div class="subBtn">
                <button id="step2_fwd" class="btn bttn1" type="button">
                  <span class="">Next</span>
                </button>
                <!--<button id="step1_fwd" class="btn btn-primary bttn1" type="button">Start Your Quote</button>-->
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="step_3" class="step_3" style="display: none;">

            <div align="center" class="tab">
              <h2>Step 2</h2>
              <h3>Contact Info</h3>

              <input placeholder="E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email">

              <input placeholder="Phone" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone1">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="auto">Submit</button>
            </div>


              <!--
                  <button type="button" class="prevBtn" id="step3_bck">
                    <span class="">Back</span>
                  </button>

               <div class="subBtn">
    <button id="get_quote" class="bttn1" type="submit">
    <span class="text">Get A Quote</span>
    </button>
-->
              <!--<button id="step1_fwd" class="btn btn-primary bttn1" type="button">Start Your Quote</button>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: Your form appears to have no way to submit it, but does appear to be hooked up for POSTing most of the data correctly. The only thing is that `<select>` should have the `name`; not the `<option>` elements.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't paste in the whole thing, I'll edit my question.

Thanks! <select> works now! Just need the date to post now.

Comment: The error message is "Move date has to be greater than today" -- Have you tried using a "greater than today" date?

Comment: @shaochuancs yeah I did and I still got the same message. I found out from someone that type="date" formats the date to `yyyy-mm-dd` rather than the format the CRM accepts which is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Apparently, I need to use some javascript to change this.